# What's a catch-all term of invocation and evocation?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

In this case, I shall define the two by the following:

Evocation - To bring out. To use a power that you have inherently, such as pulling two objects together.

"Jane evoked a fireball."

Invocation - To command or produce by speaking the name of. This includes a name you have personally given to multiple powers strung together.

"Jane invoked the name of fire, and the bonfire solo in two."

Please note that conjuration refers to the former and not the latter, magic is too broad, incantation is the latter, and enchantment is a subset of the latter.

Please note that 'Calling' works fairly well, yet it doesn't sound technical enough for my purposes.

Comment: The first two definitions in the full OED for **invoke** are *To call on (God, a deity, etc.) **in prayer or as a witness;** to appeal to for aid or protection; to summon or invite in prayer*, and *To summon (a spirit) by charms or incantation.* Their first definition for **evoke** is *To call forth; esp. to summon up (spirits, etc.) by the use of magic charms.* To my mind this means that since the definitions have considerable overlap, it's meaningless to ask for a term that "includes both" (each already alludes to the other anyway, in contexts relevant to OP).

Comment: Something like *manifest* might work.

Comment: In what way do you feel **Conjuration** does not include **Invocation**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers They overlap, sure, but are separate things, especially in the work I'm writing.

Comment: @Yeshe 'To conjure' means to expel from somewhere *by* invoking something. Invoking is the method, and it is not included in conjuration.

Answer (score 1):

**Summon**?

That fits with summoning something from within yourself (non-magical example: "She summoned the strength she needed to face her fears.") or to invoke (again non-magical example: "He summoned the butler.")